# Ansible wait_for for connecting machine to actually login

Tags: ansible

In my working environment, virtual machines are created and after creating login access information is added to them and there can be delays so just waiting for my ansible script to check if SSH is available is not enough, I actually need to check if ansible can get inside the remote machine via ssh.

Here is my old script which fails me:

```
- name: wait for instances to listen on port:22
  wait_for:
    state: started
    host: "{{ item }}"
    port: 22
  with_items: myservers
```

How can I rewrite this task snippet to achieve waiting for the localmachine can ssh into the remote machines (again not only checking if ssh is ready at the remote but it can actually authenticate to it).

Comment: As soon as SSH is listening on the port you should be able to log in.

Comment: Sadly it is not the case. It seems like my company provisions created VMs users on a scheduled and unpredictable so script should wait for actually to access. Otherwise I see 'authorization failed'.

Comment: A more common scenario is that the SSH port is open but the machine has not finished booting, and `account required pam_nologin.so` is specified in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.   (many systemd based distros do this).   In this case an ssh to the machine fails with a message like `System is booting up. See pam_nologin(8)`

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat ugly, but given your needs it might work:

```
- local_action: command ssh myuser@{{ ansible_inventory_hostname }} exit
  register: log_output
  until: log_output.stdout.find("Last login") > -1
  retries: 10
  delay: 5
```

The first line would cause your ansible host to try to ssh into the target host and immediately issue an "exit" to return control back to ansible.  Any output from that command gets stored in the `log_output` variable.  The `until` clause will check the output for the string 'Last login' (you may want to change this to something else depending on your environment), and Ansible will retry this task up to 10 times with a 5 second delay between attempts.

Answer (score 3):

Bruce P's answer was close to what I needed, but my ssh doesn't print any banner when running a command, so checking stdout is problematic.

```
- local_action: command ssh "{{ hostname }}" exit
  register: ssh_test
  until: ssh_test.rc == 0
  retries: 25
  delay: 5
```

So instead I use the return code to check for success

Answer (score 1):

As long as your Ansible user is already installed on the image you are using to create the new server instance, the wait_for command works well.

If that is not the case, then you need to poll the system that adds that user to the newly created instance for when you should continue - of course that system will have to have something to poll against...

The (very ugly) alternative is to put a static pause in your script that will wait the appropriate amount of time between the instance being created and the user being added like so:

```
- pause: seconds=1
```

Try not to though, static pauses are a bad way of solving this issue.